# Error in SQL table creation

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a data base table sales_order.

My code is as following:

```
create table sales_order( 
ono varchar2(6) check(ono like 'o%'), 
cno varchar2(6), 
orderdate date not null, 
deladder varchar2(30), 
sno varchar2(6), 
deltype char(1) check (deltype in('P','F')), 
bill char(1), 
delydate date CHECK(delydate>orderdate), 
orderstatus varcahr2(10) set default('inprocess','fullfilled','backorder' 'cancelled'),   constraint p5 primary key(ono), constraint f3 foreign key(sno) references salesman_master(sno)       );
```

Giving Following Error :

```
 delydate date CHECK(delydate>orderdate),
*
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
```

Comment: Seems obvious - your CHECK is incorrect.  Remove it.

Comment: After removing giving the same error.

Comment: If you've removed that check constraint then it _can't_ be exactly the same error...  you have however spelt VARCHAR incorrectly and your default is incorrect.

Comment: can you please modify this with any other default value. I am very new to it.

Comment: But you can't have multiple defaults... it's a contradiction to have many things equal one. So, it would be helpful if you explained what you're attempting rather than just dumping some DDL and an error message into a post. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite clear in SQL Fiddle:

```
Schema Creation Failed: ORA-02438: Column check constraint cannot reference other columns
```

Then when you fix the assorted other errors (`set default`?  `varcahr2`?  no closing `)`) it works.  Try this:

```
create table sales_order ( 
    ono varchar2(6) check(ono like 'o%'), 
    cno varchar2(6), 
    orderdate date not null, 
    deladder varchar2(30), 
    sno varchar2(6), 
    deltype char(1) check (deltype in('P','F')), 
    bill char(1), 
    delydate date, 
    orderstatus varchar2(10) check (orderstatus in ('inprocess', 'fullfilled', 'backorder', 'cancelled')),
    constraint p5 primary key(ono),
    constraint f3 foreign key(sno) references salesman_master(sno)
);
```